# Anylogic - How to access a cell in a database

Tags: java, cell, anylogic

Is there anyway I can change the value of a cell in anylogic? 
I tried to use `getValueAt` as well as `setValueAt`. Every time I try there is an error saying `getValueAt` isn't working with a database. I am pretty sure this would work in java. Why isn't it working here?

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: Show a code example to demonstrate what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
First I tried:
db_auftrag.setValueAt("2", 2, 2)
Later on I tried:
db_auftrag.setValueAt(2,2)=2
db_auftrag(2,2)=2

db_auftrag is my database. I want to write 2 in the B2 cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `insertInto` function to add a new data row or use the "update" function to amend an existing cell, type these into the AnyLogic help for a code example.

Comment: I tried this but I don't get it. Thank you very much anyway!

  

insertInto(db_auftrag)
    .columns(typ1)
    .values("1")
    .execute();

as well as

  

executeStatement("INSERT INTO db_auftrag (typ1) VALUES ('1')");

to find a good example in anylogic help, i wasn't able to.

Comment: Thanks. If there is somebody else looking to solve this problem "update" function is the function to use. I was to focused on insertinto

Answer (score 0):

To `insert into` an internal database do something like this:
https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/Inserting.html

But it seems to me, you want to `update` a value at a database. You have to use this :
https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/Updating.html

If you update, you need to specify the row you want to update. For example in column1 is an id and you want to update the value of column2. Do something like this:

```
int var = 2;    
update(db_auftrag)
.where(db_auftrag.column1.eq("parameter1"))
.set(db_auftrag.column2, var)
.execute();
```

If you want to read this value into your simulation again, do not read the cached db-tables but the original one. This has been mentioned by Gregory here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547812/7105351

Comment: Thanks, now it is working. The hint to differenciated between insert and update was very important. I was to blind.

Comment: Is there anyway to access  the column by its number?